# Bootstrap modal popup shows page content

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap

The bootstrap modal popup shows the content of the page on the popup. The popup should not show anything that is on the page. Please find the below image where youtube, facebook and twitter images on the page are visible on the popup. Can someone please help me to overcome this. Thanks in advance.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc3OA.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check what is your z-index value for social icons, if it's higher than modal value (z-index: 1050) then thats your problem.
lower social icons z-index value to less than 1050